# Iphone 6 plus keyboard letters uppercase

Tags: keyboard, iphone

I bought my Iphone 6 plus yesterday, and i was wondering is it genuine because keyboard letters when typing messages and emails are all uppercase no matter caps lock. Is it good, sorry for stupid question, but I`m new to Apple products.

Thanks

Comment: What iOS version are you using? (in settings > general > about)

Comment: Also, if you have two different questions, can you please remove the second question, and create a new question at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask - this makes it easier to answer the questions.

Comment: My Iphone 6 plus runs IOS 8.1 and my Iphone 6s runs IOS 9.1

Answer (score 1):

Apple changed the keyboard in ios 9 to make it easier to tell when the shift key is pressed. In ios 8 and below, the keyboard letters are always uppercase, but in ios 9, they are only uppercase if the shift key is pressed.

You can update to ios 9.1 by opening settings, then choosing general > software update, and choosing "install". It will take a while, so you should probably plug your device in first. This should make the keyboard match your other device.